# WSO2 - Identity server - version 7 - Issue when running Mysql script on NDB clustering

Tags: mysql, wso2-identity-server

We are trying to install IS latest version 7 with MYSQL DB using NDB cluster.
However, when running the script we are facing an issue:

- Script name: <ISKM_CARBON_HOME>/dbscripts/identity/mysql-cluster.sql
- Errors:

Warning (Code 1296): Got error 21034 'Create foreign key failed - child table has Blob or Text column and on-delete-cascade is not allowed' from NDB

Error (Code 1215): Cannot add foreign key constraint
related to the following SQL syntax:
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IDV_CLAIM (

```
-> ID          INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

-> UUID        CHAR(36) NOT NULL,

-> USER_ID     VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,

-> CLAIM_URI   VARCHAR(254),

-> IDVP_ID     CHAR(36) NOT NULL,

-> TENANT_ID   INTEGER,

-> IS_VERIFIED CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

-> METADATA    BLOB,

-> PRIMARY KEY (ID),

-> UNIQUE (CLAIM_URI, TENANT_ID, USER_ID, IDVP_ID),

->     UNIQUE (UUID),

->     FOREIGN KEY (IDVP_ID) REFERENCES IDVP(UUID) ON DELETE CASCADE

-> )ENGINE NDB;
```

ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Warning (Code 1296): Got error 21034 'Create foreign key failed - child table has Blob or Text column and on-delete-cascade is not allowed' from NDB

Error (Code 1215): Cannot add foreign key constraint

and another error related to missing table when creating an index on it:

ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'this_is_from_Node1.SCOPE' doesn't exist
-- SCOPE --

CREATE INDEX API_ID_NAME_INDEX ON SCOPE (API_ID, NAME);

To note that similar issues are faced with older versions.

Please help as the specified errors are usually a limitation in mysql ndb cluster.

Comment: I'll be honest, not sure what help you need from us here! If this a limitation of NDB cluster, then either you need to remove the cascaded delete or you need to change the table engine.

Comment: I am asking mainly certified wso2 people. because if they support clustering and they provided scripts for it, it should be working so i need their help to understand why it is not.

Comment: Then you should be asking their support, not here on a community site.

Comment: Checked out mysql documentation on foreign keys and it says this restriction was introduced in v8.0.16 as ndb was leaking memory with cascaded deletes involving text/blob fields. It was reported as bugs and mysql decided to remove the option rather than fix the bugs.